# Show that $MNPQ$ is a square

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, vectors, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

Let $ ABCD $ a quadrilateral s.t. $AC=BD $ and $m (\angle AOD)=30°$ where $O=AC\cap BD $.

Let $\triangle ABM, \triangle DCN, \triangle ADN, \triangle CBQ $ equilateral triangles with $Int (\triangle ABM)\cap Int (ABCD)=\emptyset$,  $Int (\triangle DCP)\cap Int (ABCD)=\emptyset$,  $Int (\triangle ADN)\cap Int (ABCD) \neq \emptyset$,  $Int (\triangle CBQ)\cap Int (ABCD)\neq\emptyset$.

Show that $MNPQ$ is a square.

I have no idea how to start.[image]

Comment: Just drawn a picture and it didn't look like a square to me.

Comment: Edit: I think I see the problem here. All equilateral triangles should be drawn in the *opposite* direction and the statement would be true. I still don't know how to approach though...

Comment: Ok so here's an idea assuming that the equilateral triangles are meant to be drawn oppositely: Rotate ΔABC by 60° around B and you'll get ΔMBQ. Do this 4 times and use AC=BD, and you'll find that MNPQ is a rhombus. Moreover if you keep track of all the angles of rotation and use ∠AOD = 30°, you'll find that the angles of the rhombus are all right, and hence it is a square.

Comment: As given it's clearly false.  $m\angle AMB =60$ and $m\angle MBA = 60$ and $m\angle QBC = 60$ so $Q$ is in the interior of $\angle AMB$.  As is $N$ so $m\angle NMQ < m\angle AMB = 60 < 90$.  Can't be a square.  But if all the intersections are empty so the equi triangles pop out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R^{\alpha}_O$ be a rotation in the plain by an angle $\alpha$ around a point $O$.

Easy to see that to rotate a vector by an angle $\alpha$ it's the same to rotate this vector around his tail.

Now, by using the beautiful  Daniel Mathias's picture we obtain:
$$R^{90^{\circ}}\left(\vec{NM}\right)=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{NA}+\vec{AM}\right)\right)=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(\vec{DA}+\vec{AB}\right)=$$ 
$$=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(\vec{DB}\right)=R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{AC}\right)=R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}\right)=\vec{MB}+\vec{BQ}=\vec{MQ},$$
which says $NM\perp MQ$ and $NM=MQ.$

Also,
$$R^{90^{\circ}}\left(\vec{QP}\right)=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{QC}+\vec{CP}\right)\right)=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(\vec{BC}+\vec{CD}\right)=$$ 
$$=R^{30^{\circ}}\left(\vec{BD}\right)=R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{CA}\right)=R^{60^{\circ}}\left(\vec{CB}+\vec{BA}\right)=\vec{QB}+\vec{BM}=\vec{QM},$$
which says $QM\perp PQ$ and $QM=PQ.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: There is a synthetic proof? I try to prove it with congruences of triangles.

Comment: I like your solution +1, do you like mine?

Comment: Do you have some more problems like this solved vith rotation?

Comment: @greedoid Yes, of course. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079152

Comment: Yes I saw that one, it is nice. That is all you have? Do you have some pdf file with problems like this?

Comment: @greedoid I have no PDF about it. You can try to solve all problems with squares or equilateral triangles by this method. It works sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the desired result. Note that the intersection/non-intersection is opposite from the description.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Knowing complex numbers, this one is easy to solve. We need just this lemma:

**Lemma**: If $|\vec{XY}| =|\vec{ZT}|$ and $\angle (\vec{XY},\vec{ZT}) = \alpha$ then $$ZT = \varepsilon\cdot  XY$$
where $\varepsilon = \cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha$

---

So it is enought to prove $MN = i\cdot MQ\;\;\; (*)$. We have 
$$DB=\varepsilon AC \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;{\rm where}\;\;\;\;\varepsilon = \cos {\pi \over 6} + i \sin {\pi \over 6} $$
and if $\delta = \cos {\pi \over 3} + i \sin {\pi \over 3} $ then $$MA = \delta MB \implies M = {A-\delta B\over 1-\delta}$$
$$QC = \delta QB \implies Q = {C-\delta B\over 1-\delta}$$
$$NA  = \delta ND \implies N = {A-\delta D\over 1-\delta}$$

thus $$MN ={A-\delta D\over 1-\delta}-{A-\delta B\over 1-\delta} = {\delta\over 1-\delta}DB$$  $$ =  {\delta\over 1-\delta}\varepsilon \cdot AC=i{AC\over 1-\delta} = iMQ$$

and we are done.